# he found the key just _______ the front door. what should fill the blank?

Tags: prepositions

I would like to know the answer in the blank .....What does the word "just" indicate ?  Can it be "key just to the front door"?

Comment: Just under/near the front door! Precisely under/near the front door!

Comment: *To* would work. "He found the key just to the front door, not the master key to both front and back doors." That would be better as "the key to just the front door," but word-order often gets distorted in speech. It just goes to show: **prepositions change meaning.** We can't say what should fill in the blank without knowing what that sentence is supposed to mean.

Comment: The prepositional-phrase modifier _just_ here ('right' would be an alternative) makes sense and is most often found collocating with _by_.

Comment: Questions like these are usually taken from a set, and/or an exercise. If you tell us what the object of exercise is; what the exercise is practicing, the rest should be easy.  For example, have you recently studied prepositions of place? **Beneath**, **next to**, **by** or **on** could work. But how can we know?

Comment: “He found the key just [now, after having been looking for it for fifteen minutes. As soon as he found it, he put it in his pocket, slung his satchel over his shoulder and, hoping he’d not miss the school bus, sprinted out] the front door.”

Comment: Just fit the front door.  Just scratched the front door.  Just loved the front door.  Just ate the front door.

Comment: @HotLicks Bon appétit!

Answer (score 1):

You haven't given us quite enough context to be sure, but I will give you the most likely answer.

*Just* can be applied to an adjective or adverb to show that the bare minimum requirements to merit the description are satisfied.  So

> just inside the front door

means

> in the room behind the door but so close to the door that it would probably be touching it if the door were closed

"Just behind the door" would have the same meaning.  So there is a small range of words or phrases likely to fill that blank:

- inside
- behind
- in front of
- under
- above
- beside

I haven't given you an exhaustive list but this is the kind of word (and the most likely set of candidates) required.

That said, a slightly different meaning of *just* is "Exactly what was wanted/required.  "Just perfect" has that second meaning, whereas "Just enough" has the first meaning.  So using my imagination to consider rather unlikely scenarios (since we have no proper context)...

> He found the key just like the door

could mean either

> He had thought the door ridiculous and he thought the key precisely as stupid.

or

> He discovered the key in the same way he had located the door

Or using another subtly different meaning of *just* (purely, simply, for no other reason), since you haven't said it should be just one word...

> He found the key just to spite the door

My first suggestion is rather more likely.